# XLST template to be used to remove extra declarations from CreateInterfaceRequest tag

Tags: xslt, soap

The below is input:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <CreateInterfaceRequest Destination="KISTA" CreatedBy="ONETM">
      <Source_ObjectID>TEST24</Source_ObjectID>
    </CreateInterfaceRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And I want the output to be

```
<CreateInterfaceRequest> /* this needs to be as it is
  <Source_ObjectID>TEST24</Source_ObjectID>
</CreateInterfaceRequest>
```

with SOAP enclosures. Remove (Destination="KISTA" CreatedBy="ONETM" )

I used this XSLT template match code

```
<xsl:template match="CreateInterfaceRequest/*"> 
  <CreateInterfaceRequest> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </CreateInterfaceRequest> 
<xsl:template>
```

but it gives the error

> template match cannot be declared in BODY

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the XSLT template match you have used? Thank you!

Comment: @ShilpaSegu: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42051249/edit) the question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Done..Let me know if you want me to add anything

Comment: You really need to edit your question to show the XSLT. It would probably helped if you showed a complete XSLT that demonstrated the problem, rather than just the single template, as it might be that the template in question is not actually being called. Thanks!

Comment: I edited your XSLT code into your question and (maybe) improved the clarity of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This template is one possibility to achieve this. It simply removes the namespace of the `Source_ObjectID` node and copies all `CreateInterfaceRequest` nodes (and also removes all of its attributes).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="//CreateInterfaceRequest"> 
    <CreateInterfaceRequest> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </CreateInterfaceRequest> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Source_ObjectID"> 
    <xsl:element name="Source_ObjectID" namespace=""> 
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CreateInterfaceRequest>
    <Source_ObjectID>TEST24</Source_ObjectID>
</CreateInterfaceRequest>
```

Comment: Im getting error as:xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:template' element..Where should this tag be placed.

Comment: @ShilpaSegu: Your question must be wrong, because in my answer there is no `<xsl:template>` as a child of another `<xsl:template>` which you could easily verify.